# Powershell script to restart Apache Process

Tags: apache, powershell, apache2.2

I am using powershell script to restart Apache service once Apache process reaches a memory threshold.
The script will run 2-3 times a minute as scheduled in Task Manager.

In the script below, do I need to use start-sleep commandlet and if so, where should be best to place it and for how many seconds to make it sleep?

```
$Threshold = 200 * 1024 * 1024;     # Bytes (209,715,200 bytes = 0.195GB)
$ServiceName = my service name;

Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "localhost" -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | where { $_.Name -like "httpd*" } | foreach {
    $procobj = $_;

    if($procobj.workingset -gt $Threshold)
    {  
        stop-Service $ServiceName;

        start-Service $ServiceName;

        $stamp = Get-Date
        echo $($stamp + " Started service: " + $ServiceName);
        #sleep 5;  //Do I need this and if so, where should it be placed?
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Apache may have 2 or more processes and Get-Wmi will return them as httpd, httpd#1, httpd#2, ....
The reason I am asking this is that the loop will check for these processes working set, so imagine there are 3 processed returned: httpd, httpd#1, and httpd#2 and imaginge both httpd#1 and httpd#2 have reached the threshhold.
Note that within the loop, I am restarting ***service*** which will restart process.  Since 2 of my httpd processes have reached threshold, I will then restart service 2-ice.  I am trying to ensure that service restart will occur only once even if more than one of processes have reached threshhold.  Not sure if start-sleep would solve this or if there is a better way.

Much appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to make this script sleep it does not re-run itself. You need to schedule it to run periodically.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that.  Yes it is scheduled to run automatically 2-3 times a minute.  I have updated my post.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Neossian also please note that the script is a loop.  Apache may have multiple processes running such as httpd, httpd#1, httpd#2, ...

Comment: I see the loop, but it runs once, does what it needs to and then dies. You won't get a runaway loop with this because all your loops are finite. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with a start-sleep?

Comment: @Neossian I added an update to explain what I am trying to do.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Threshold = 200 * 1024 * 1024;     # Bytes (209,715,200 bytes = 0.195GB)
$ServiceName = my service name;

Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "localhost" -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | where { $_.Name -like "httpd*" } | foreach {
    $procobj = $_;

    if($procobj.workingset -gt $Threshold)
    {  
        stop-Service $ServiceName;

        start-Service $ServiceName;

        $stamp = Get-Date
        echo $($stamp + " Started service: " + $ServiceName);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that starting/stopping service from Powershell like I do above may not be a good idea. A better way is to use httpd -k restart to restart it gracefully. So, for those that might need something like this, instead of 3 lines above (stop-service, start-service), replace them with call to your httpd.exe like this: C:\your\path\to\Apache\bin\httpd.exe -k restart -n "YOURSERVICENAME" -f "C:\your\path\to\Apache\conf\httpd-YOURNAME.conf";. If you use default service name, then just alleverything after and including "-n".